# Automatically shift data down once new data is copied in the same cells using button?

Tags: excel, vba, button

I am trying to use a macro button that once clicked copys a set of data A3:E22 from sheet 1 to A3:E22 on sheet 3. After it is copied, I want the data from sheet 1 cleared so that i can start to input new data in the cells that were just cleared.

I am having trouble shifting the data on sheet 3 down so that once I repeat the cycle of copying data from sheet 1 to sheet 3 again, the data that i previously copied on sheet 3 will shift down automatically and keep shifting down as long as i repeat the copy cycle.

Is there a certain set of code that I can program to my button for the copy cycle from sheet 1 to sheet 3 so that the data on sheet 3 will automatically shift down?

11/05/14
I've tried the code from the reply and it works great on a new workbook but I'm having trouble transferring this code to my existing workbook. I keep getting a "Subscript out of range" error where the "Set S1...". do I need to rename my worksheets or call S1 something different to refer to worksheet 1? I am a rookie at coding so any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Shift down **before** the copy so the new paste destination will be blank and available.

Comment: 11/05/14 I've tried the code from the reply and it works great on a new workbook but I'm having trouble transferring this code to my existing workbook. I keep getting a "Subscript out of range" error where the "Set S1...". do I need to rename my worksheets or call S1 something different to refer to worksheet 1? I am a rookie at coding so any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some typical code:

```
Sub TransferData()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s3 As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range, r3 As Range
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set r1 = s1.Range("A3:E22")
    Set r3 = s3.Range("A3:E22")

    s3.Activate
    r3.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Set r3 = s3.Range("A3:E22")

    s1.Activate
    r1.Copy r3
    r1.Clear
End Sub
```